# Extracting text from a lookup field in a SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, lookup-column, display-form

I switched from InfoPath to the Designer forms. In the list I have a Lookupfield that Points to another list. In the Control modes Edit and New the select boxes are created automatically using the usual elements

```
<SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff6{$Pos}" ControlMode="Edit" FieldName="Betrieb" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff6',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Betrieb')}"/>
<SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff6description{$Pos}" FieldName="Betrieb" ControlMode="Edit"/>
```

The Problem arises in the ViewForm, where I usually use the following:

```
<xsl:value-of select="@Betrieb"/>
```

But since Betrieb is a Lookup field, it creates an a element and in the form i see:

```
<a href="http://portal/projects/buchungsportal/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=4&ListId={f1b5206b-3d88-4ea3-8aba-6c26b9dd07f8}&ID=1146&RootFolder=*">THE VALUE I WANT TO DIAPLAY</a>
```

How do I extract only `THE VALUE I WANT TO DISPLAY`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the substring options available in XSLT to get what you want substring-before and substring-after. Like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before("&le;/a&gt;", substring-after("*&quot;&gt;", @Betrieb))"/>
```

Not fully tested, the encodings might be off for the greater than, less than, and double quote characters.

Edit:
This also works, it will render a hyperlink though, not the value.

Comment: Well, ist a Little bit dirty... i thought there would be a SharePoint Feature or something else.

Comment: That's just the way Lookup columns work in Sharepoint and DVWPs/XSLT, they are stored as an ID value pair. You could try the <xsl:value-of select="@Betrieb" disable-output-escaping="yes"/> but I don't think that is going to give the right result.

Comment: `<xsl:value-of select="@Betrieb" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>` Works, it puts the a tag as HTML instead of a simply text node. Thanks Man!

Comment: Ok, when you said the value, I thought you wanted just the display name of the Lookup field which is why I went the substring route. Using the disable-output-escaping will render as a hyperlink.

Answer (score 2):

select above should be:

```
    substring-before(substring-after(@Lookup, '&gt;'), '&lt;/a&gt;')
```